# The IV for AES-128

Tags: aes, initialization-vector

I'm trying to understand this:

> [AES_128] REQUIRES the same 16-octet Initialization Vector (IV) to be
> supplied when encrypting and decrypting.  Varying this IV increases
> the strength of the cipher.
>
> An IV attribute on an EXT-X-KEY tag with a KEYFORMAT of "identity"
> specifies an Initialization Vector that can be used when decrypting
> Media Segments encrypted with that Key file.  IV values for AES-128
> are 128-bit numbers.
>
> An EXT-X-KEY tag with a KEYFORMAT of "identity" that does not have
> an    IV attribute indicates that the Media Sequence Number is to be
> used    as the IV when decrypting a Media Segment, by putting its
> big-endian    binary representation into a 16-octet (128-bit) buffer
> and padding    (on the left) with zeros.

[From here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-16#section-5.2)

My question is:
The iv shuld be like this (for 10 at dec.):
`000000000000000A` ?
or at binary?

Thank you!

Comment: 16 bytes (or octets, which is slightly more precise) can be represented by 32 hexadecimal digits, not 16 of course; one hex digit per nibble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The iv shuld be like this (for 10 at dec.):
>   000000000000000A ? 
>   or at binary?

The HTTP headers have to be encoded as text. So I'd assume you should provide `000000000000000A` (as far I know you may not send unencoded binary values in the http header)

Reading the draft something stroke my eye:

> entire resource MUST be encrypted using
>     AES-128 CBC with PKCS7 padding

using CBC mode means the IV should be unpredictable as far I know

> An EXT-X-KEY tag with a KEYFORMAT of "identity" that does not have an
>      IV attribute indicates that the Media Sequence Number is to be used

That breaks the previous requirements for unpredictable IV and the cipher becomes easily malleable. Maybe the authors rely on SSL to mitigate this issue.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm tring to find the IV for decription .ts files....